# React Native WebView hardware keyboard focus skipping first element

Tags: react-native, webview, keyboard-focus

I have a password confirmation form inside WebView and I need it to be usable with hardware keyboard.
When I connect hardware keyboard and hit Tab, once focus enters WebView component it skips first focusable element and goes to the second one. Here's simplified version of the screen.
[Video](https://youtube.com/shorts/PaF_0EMnzvI?feature=share). Has anyone faced this issue and how do you overcome it?

I use `react-native-webview` library.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround: inside the page that appears inside the WebView add following

```
document.body.tabIndex = 0;
```

This will set body as first focusable element and focus will jump over it (almost invisible).